# Difference between CGImage and UIImage. How costly is the conversion?

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgimage

As far as I know `CGImage` contains bitmap data, but how is that different from `UIImage`? What does `UIImage` store what `CGImage` doesn't?

Does `UIImage -> CGImage` and `CGImage -> UIImage` conversions effect on the performance?

Comment: Please specify your question. And if you are willing to know about CIImage and UIImage or their conversions please first read Apple Document.

Comment: @ChanWarde I've read this article: https://medium.com/@ranleung/uiimage-vs-ciimage-vs-cgimage-3db9d8b83d94 but still didn't quite get it, so this is why I am asking.

Comment: @ChanWarde. I'm talking about about conversion effect on performance not the API. Please first read the question. If you are that smart, you can at least provide a link in the description

Comment: Maybe I am not that smart but I have worked on CIImage, CGImage, Quartz Core. You should specify your need for the question.  Let me explain something UIImage is a format which is used to show image visually and if you want to edit the image you need row image which is CGImage. You can not edit UIImage directly. You are asking about performance but regarding what??

Comment: @ChanWarde I know that UIImage is immutable, therefore I can not modify it, so I need to go back to CGImage in order to perform some changes. But does this mean, that UIImage does not store bitmap data in it's class declaration? The question is more or less about internals. Why do we need 2 classes?

Comment: In my case I have a stream of CIImages that I further convert to CGImage in order to perform some computation (like variance of an image (I need pixel data for that, so CIImage won't work in this case)). Currently I am performing CGImage to UIIMage conversion on the Background thread, but is it really that costly to convert CGImage to UIImage and if yes, then why?

Comment: It's not that costly to convert images in a different format. But if you perform any modification on the image it cost your device memory depending upon the size of the image. It will row image in memory + many other classes to modify that image for e.g. CGContext, CIFilter etc. You can test it performing simple two action UIImage -> CGImage then CGImage -> UIImage.